# Python: PyQt QTreeview example - selection

Tags: python, qt, tree, qtreeview

I'm using Python 2.7 and Qt designer and I'm new to MVC:
I have a View completed within Qt to give me a directory tree list, and the controller in place to run things. My question is:

**Given a Qtree view, how may I obtain a directory once a dir is selected?**

[image]

Code snap shot is below, I suspect it's SIGNAL(..) though I'm unsure:

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  plot = pyqtSignal()

  def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # create model
    model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath( QtCore.QDir.currentPath() )

    # set the model
    self.ui.treeView.setModel(model)

    **QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)**

  def test(self):
    print "hello!"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The signal you're looking for is [selectionChanged](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreeview.html#selectionChanged) emmited by the **selectionModel** owned by your tree. This signal is emmited with the **selected** item as first argument and the **deselected** as second, both are instances of [QItemSelection](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemselection.html).

So you might want to change the line:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)
```

to

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView.selectionModel(), QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged()'), self.test)
```

Also I recommend you to use the [new style for signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). Redefine your `test` function as:

```
 @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QItemSelection, QItemSelection")
 def test(self, selected, deselected):
     print("hello!")
     print(selected)
     print(deselected)
```

Here you have a working example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Main(QtGui.QTreeView):

  def __init__(self):

    QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self)
    model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath( QtCore.QDir.currentPath() )
    self.setModel(model)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.selectionModel(), QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)'), self.test)

  @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QItemSelection, QItemSelection")
  def test(self, selected, deselected):
      print("hello!")
      print(selected)
      print(deselected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## PyQt5

In PyQt5 is a little bit different (thanks to Carel and saldenisov for comments and aswer.)

> ... connect moved from being an object method to a method acting upon the attribute when PyQt went from 4 to 5

So instead the known:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)
```

now you write:

```
class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...  
        self.setModel(model)
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.test)  # Note that the the signal is now a attribute of the widget.
```

Here is a the example (by saldenisov) using PyQt5.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView,QFileSystemModel,QApplication

class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath('C:\\')
        self.setModel(model)
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self, signal):
        file_path=self.model().filePath(signal)
        print(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Have you by chance tried this in PyQt5 ? I receive "Attribute Error connect is not an attribute of QObject"

Comment: I also have problems with PyQt5. Could you provide code for PyQt5 as well?

Comment: @Carel, see my answer below

Answer (score 5):

In PyQt5 it can be done in this way:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView,QFileSystemModel,QApplication

class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath('C:\\')
        self.setModel(model)
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self, signal):
        file_path=self.model().filePath(signal)
        print(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response. Perhaps for others it'd help to mention that connect moved from being an object method to a method acting upon the attribute when PyQt went from 4 to 5. Though I believe the documentation stating this is more prevalent these days.

Comment: For those who prefer English to Cantonese (@Carel: "from object method to methond acting upon the attribute"): Connect went from a class/static method on QObject to instance method on the signal object.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you would like the directory or file name selected.

This is what I do:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.resize(600,400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Treeview Example")

        self.treeview = QtGui.QTreeView(self)

        self.treeview.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.treeview.model.setRootPath( QtCore.QDir.currentPath() )
        self.treeview.setModel(self.treeview.model)
        self.treeview.setColumnWidth(0, 200)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeview)

        self.treeview.clicked.connect(self.on_treeview_clicked)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeview_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.treeview.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())

        # path or filename selected
        fileName = self.treeview.model.fileName(indexItem)
        # full path/filename selected
        filePath = self.treeview.model.filePath(indexItem)

        print(fileName)
        print(filePath)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this alternative to get the file name...

Instead of:

```
indexItem = self.treeview.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())

# path or filename selected
fileName = self.treeview.model.fileName(indexItem)
```

I tried:

```
# path or filename selected
fileName = index.internalPointer().fileName
```

Which also seems to work...