# SetRootPath doesn't set work as expected

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I have used part of a code (PyQt5) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993895/python-pyqt-qtreeview-example-selection/32158134#32158134)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView,QFileSystemModel,QApplication

class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath('C:\\')
        self.setModel(model)
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self, signal):
        file_path=self.model().filePath(signal)
        print(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And i have a problem with this line

> model.setRootPath('C:\')

When i run the program it always shows drives like C: D: just not the content of C:\ or even if i type "C:\Users\" or a path that doesn't even exists, it always just shows, see attached image, What am i doing wrong?

Image of PyQt Program showing file manager

[image]

I am using:
Windows 10, 
PyCharm, 
Python 3.5, 
PyQt5,

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must indicate to the `QTreeView` what is your root item with `setRootIndex()`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView,QFileSystemModel,QApplication

class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.setModel(model)
        model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.setRootIndex(model.index("C:"))
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self, signal):
        file_path=self.model().filePath(signal)
        print(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```